# Best approach to handle spring boot polling among Async, DeferredResult & CompletableFeature for status polling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

> I am implementing an onboarding application with REST API which
> involves saving(onboarding)details to the table based on the
> external service validation.This would be a post request. This
> creation involves multiple steps and may take a while.
>
> I do not want
> the user to wait on it. I simply return a **202** response with a status
> url and unique id for the client request and start some threads on the
> server to create the object.I am using **@Async** annotation from Spring
> Boot to handle The client is supposed to check back to see whether the
> request is completed or not, in the future. The flow goes like this:

The client POSTs the object.
The server responds with a 202 Accepted code with a status ur header /my-app/
The client does a GET on /my-app/
Get the status if it the resource exists.

Incase of

```
>     Object creation is still in progress(client should check again after sometime).
>     Some Error occured(This one is pretty sf 404 and it won't save)
```

Question:

> During save to db is there a way to share the status to client saying
> its still under progress when they poll instead of saying 404 .Basically how to
> differentiate 404 with in progress?

Here is my @Async example

Controller

```
 @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;
           @PostMapping(
            value = "/service/app",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public Object onBoardApp (
            @Parameter(description = "Name of Service", required = true)
            @PathVariable("serviceName") final String serviceName,
            @RequestBody final SampleRequest app)
        {
            try {
                sampleSerice.onBoardingApplication(app, serviceName);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("/service/"+appId+"/status", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
               
            }
        }

    @GetMapping(
            value = "/service/"+appId+"/status",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         public SampleResponse getStatus (
                @Parameter(description = "service", required = true)
                @PathVariable("serviceName") final String serviceName,
                @Parameter(description = "appId", required = true)
                @PathVariable("appId") final String appId)
            {
                try {
                  SampleResponse response= ourService.getStatus(appId, serviceName);
                  return  response;
                }
                catch (final Exception e) {
                  //Exception will be handled.
                }
            }
```

Service

```
@Async
@Trasactional
public SampleResponse onboardApplication (app, serviceName)
    {
        try {
        //Call external api and do validation and save 
         sampleRepository.save(String  serviceName,String  appId)
        catch (final Exception e) {
            //Exception will be thrown.
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.